# What do status 1 and status 5 entail? (R)

Tags: r, error

I'm running the following code using `gdalUtils`:

```
for (i in 1:20035){
  sds <- get_subdatasets(files[i])
  gdal_translate(sds[1], dst_dataset = filename[i])
}
```

It is a loop that turns `hdf` snow cover data into `tif` rasters.

The loop works, but every once in a while, it runs into a file that it doesn't like for some reason and throws this error message:

```
Error in split1[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdalinfo.exe" 
"MYD10A1.A2003177.h09v04.006.2016071002205.hdf"' had status 1
```

Sometimes it give the same message, but status 5 instead. If I start the loop over, but start it at the file *after* the one that gave me trouble, it usually works. The problems is, I have a *lot* of files. I don't have the time to keep restarting it every time it does this.

Is there a way to make the loop continue and skip the files it doesn't like? What could be causing status 1 and status 5 in this context? How do I avoid this?

Comment: Hard to say why something fails without your data. Does that file exist? Is it corrupted? Is it different to the other somehow? If you want to trap errors and continue in R, look at the `try` function.

Comment: @Spacedman, loading one of the problem files into Arc shows me that it is indeed an `invalid raster`. Is there a function to identify the rest of the invalid rasters so I can remove them before I start my `gdal_translate` loop?

Comment: @Spacedman, I think that approach will be preferable to the `try` function, because then I will know exactly which rasters I need to replace.

Comment: You can use `try` to do something and trap the ones that fail and do something else. I'll write a short example as answer.

Comment: Also: the error codes are errors from the gdalinfo command but I can't see any documentation of the error codes. Although maybe here: http://www.gdal.org/cpl__error_8h.html but 5 and 1 aren't v informative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to process in a loop and trap errors.

First, a test processing function that returns the number of letters in its argument, unless the argument is the word "two" in which case it tries to stop:

```
process=function(f){
 if(f=="two"){
  stop("CRASH!")
 }
 return(nchar(f))
}
files = c("one","two","three","four")
```

Run without protection and its stops on the second item:

```
for(file in files){
  print(file)
  n = process(file)
  print(n)
}
[1] "one"
[1] 3
[1] "two"
Error in process(file) : CRASH!
```

Put the processing in a `try` block and test for an error condition. Do something if there's an error, and carry on:

```
for(file in files){
  print(file)
  n = try(
     process(file))
  if(inherits(n,"try-error")){
    n = -1
    message("Processing ",file," failed")
    }
  print(n)
}

[1] "one"
[1] 3
[1] "two"
Error in process(file) : CRASH!
Processing two failed
[1] -1
[1] "three"
[1] 5
[1] "four"
[1] 4
```